# Use avy to select distant word or line and paste at point

Tags: yank, avy, selection

Is there a way to use avy or a similar in-buffer selection tool to quickly select a word or line to paste at the current point?

For the following buffer an example workflow for proposed functionality would be:

```
line 1 - reallyLongSymbol
line 2 - bravo
line 3 - <POINT_HERE>
```

- At line 3, realize I want to paste `reallyLongSymbol` at the current point.
- `M-x avy-select-word-and-paste` (made-up)
- Press the key combo that corresponds to `reallyLongSymbol`
- `reallyLongSymbol` is inserted at POINT.

The buffer is now as follows:

```
line 1 - reallyLongSymbol
line 2 - bravo
line 3 - reallyLongSymbol<POINT_HERE>
```

Ideally, this would work for other targets like lines and urls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

avy already supports what you want. See `avy-dispatch-alist`.

However, the default actions are not enough. I have the following function in my config (here it copies a sexp, but you can change it to copy a line):

```
(defun my-avy-action-copy-and-yank (pt)
  "Copy and yank sexp starting on PT."
  (avy-action-copy pt)
  (yank))
```

Then assign a key to the function in `avy-dispatch-alist`. I use `p` here:

```
(setq avy-dispatch-alist '((?c . avy-action-copy)
                           (?k . avy-action-kill-move)
                           (?K . avy-action-kill-stay)
                           (?m . avy-action-mark)
                           (?p . my-avy-action-copy-and-yank)))
```

To use it: before you jump to `reallyLongSymbol`, first press `p`, then the letter combination for jumping to `reallyLongSymbol`. Note that you can't use `p` in `avy-keys` since it is now reserved for the `my-avy-action-copy-and-yank`.

This is a really awesome feature and you can easily add other actions you want.

Comment: This is so cool.  One tweak I made.  `k` and `K` didn't seem to work so I used `x` and `X` which also matches the default binding.

Comment: @JoeS You're right. I changed some of the keys and I just copied part of the code from my config and I forgot to change them back when posting the answer. You just need to make sure the keys used in the `avy-dispatch-alist` don't overlap the `avy-keys`, which are used for selection. Anyway, glad it helps.

Answer (score 3):

cute-jumpers answer is perfectly functional. If you want to bind the action to another key rather than use avy's internal dispatch process then the following adapted code works quite well:

```
(defun my-avy-paste-word (char)
  "Paste a word selected with avy."
  (interactive (list (read-char "char:" t)))
  (let ((avy-action #'avy-action-copy))
    (when (avy-jump (concat "\\b" (string char)))
      (yank))))
```

Answer (score 0):

for this example you can use dynamic abbrev.

type "r" "M-/"

If you want to use avy, then assuming you have avy-goto-char bound to something like M-p, then

```
"C-SPC"   # set-mark, to remember where we are
"M-p the_correct_character_from_overlay" # avy-goto-char, goto place
"C-SPC"   # set-mark, start the region to copy
"M-f"     # forward-word, or C-e if you want to select a line...
"M-w"     # copy-region-as-kill, to copy the region
"C-x C-SPC" # pop-global-mark, get back to where we were
"C-y"     # yank, paste in the stuff we copied.
```

I know it looks a bit long (9 key combinations) but they will soon flow off the fingers.