# Advanced paste region with avy and expand region

Tags: text-editing, avy

Following the
[Use avy to select distant word or line and paste at point](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27979/use-avy-to-select-distant-word-or-line-and-paste-at-point?rq=1)
thread I want the following action - select a letter as in the thread, when the letters for avy selection arrive press a number x, yank the region selected by expand region `er/expand-region` where expand region is counted/extended x times and then paste it at the current spot.

If no number is given the standard behavior as in the source thread should be provided, if a number is given the 'expand region pasting' as described here should be the action.
I am using doom emacs on Mac OS.

So far the function looks like this:

```
(defun my-avy-paste-word (char)
  "Paste a word selected with avy."
  (interactive (list (read-char "char:" t)))
  (let ((avy-action #'avy-action-copy))
    (when (avy-jump (concat "\\b" (string char)))
      (yank))))
```

Questions:

a) How can I choose only candidates below or above, so candidates above and below the cursor are chosen.

b) How can I have `er/expand-region` with an argument responsible for how much I put into my kill ring before pasting it at point.